# Left menu overlapses with my footer on my wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, overlap

This is my site http://yannicktemp.comuv.com/?page_id=48,

however when u click on "onderhoudsproblemen" (http://yannicktemp.comuv.com/?page_id=58). U can see that the left menu overlapses with my footer, so I want my footer to move down, or in other words, my content div should stretch out.

I know this is a CSS problem, but I can't seem to get it right.

Any help is really appreciated,

thanks in advance

Comment: Or maybe I should use a table?

Answer (score 1):

You should set min-height property for your primary div in the css. Set it to something like 300px. That should do the work.